# Why does this warning always show up? ("Boolean method 'areNotificationsEnabled' is always inverted")

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Why does the following warning always show up?

> Boolean method 'areNotificationsEnabled' is always inverted

**Code**

```
public boolean areNotificationsEnabled() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        return notificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled();
    }
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    return notificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled();
}
```

**Gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ...
    }
```

I can add `@SuppressWarnings("BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted")` and ignore this warning, but what is wrong with my method?

Comment: what is your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` `? is it greater than android N ?

Comment: @Teo Check Edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning means this method always will return false, because you are always using `!` inside a statement like `if(!requirementChecker.areNotificationsEnabled())`.

But if you add another statement without `!`, like `if(requirementChecker.areNotificationsEnabled())`, then the warning will be removed.

Comment: The warning still in screen when I remove first statement

Comment: I found the problem, In other class I always used `if(!requirementChecker.areNotificationsEnabled())` so always will be false.

Comment: Please edit your answer with my solution to select this is correct answer